# How can I fix an iframe's sub-page's height to inherit?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<iframe id="filehandler" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height:1000%" 
  scrolling="no" src="loadindex.php" onload='adjustMyFrameSize();'  
  name="content-part">
</iframe>
```

The page `loadindex.php` contains another sub page. It's not an iframe, but the page has more contents. This page takes its height as `loadindex.php`'s height. How can I fix the height to be inherited from the subpage?

Comment: seriously: what? please rephrase your question!

Comment: I've made some (massive) edits to your post. Please review them and make sure they are correct.

Comment: Also, you should really be careful when you're posting code examples. If this code is exactly what you've got in your code, you should fix `height:1000%` first and then see if you still have problems.